# How can I pass proper querystring when Search from Drupal using my custom search box?

Tags: javascript, uri, search

I have this search form in my drupal site.

```
<form id="mysearch" method="get" action="<?php echo $base_url.'/search/node/'; ?>">
   <input type="text" maxlength="150" id="search" name="s" class="input">
   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="button">
</form>
```

I have problem is that when I am submit the form it will pass the query like that

```
http://mysite.com/search/node/?s=xyz
```

Here I would like to change the URL something like this to search in my site.

```
http://mysite.com/search/node/xyz
```

Can anyone help me how can i achieve this thing.

I have put this code for URL Change:

```
$("#adminbarsearch").submit(function(e) {
    $url = $("#adminbarsearch").attr("action") + $( "input:first" ).val();
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $url;
});
```

Instead of this Can we change the URL by using the `.htaccess`

Comment: jQuery code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default search block for Drupal, it will give you the functionality you need.

**EDIT**: Go to Structure > Blocks and enable your Search Form Block by adding it to a region.

If you perform a search using your default search block, it will redirect to a path in the format /search/node/QUERY where QUERY is what you are searching for.

By default the search form outputs (for example):

```
<div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block-container">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="content">
                <form action="/" method="post" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <div>
                    <div class="container-inline">
                        <h2 class="element-invisible">Search form</h2>
                            <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-search-block-form">
                                <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-search-block-form--2">Search</label>
                                <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
                                <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" class="form-submit">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-4gEUIDHcVH7lHHH3JpkfkVs9xBmPhHXdDQAMFMF9dHA">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="afNo5gRQlaauXmqeZYDf80o5dEwKlg0VP6U-Ir8-p6k">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if I search for "test", it redirects to /search/node/test

Comment: Can you explain more How I can pass param in querystring without "?"

Comment: I've added more info to my answer